# How to update nested object within mongodb document?

Tags: mongodb

```
> db.course.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("602e6fda34d693c13b2fc916"),
        "name" : "Java programming",
        "price" : "10"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("602e6fda34d693c13b2fc917"),
        "title" : "Android AP",
        "price" : "10.2",
        "faq" : {
                "q1" : "answer1",
                "q2" : "answer2"
        }
}
```

This is the structure of the object. I am trying to update `faq` object without deleting `q1` and `q2` in the process. Want to insert `q3`. Any idea how?

Comment: `db.course.updateOne({ title: "Android AP" }, { $set: { "faq.q3": "answer3" } });`

Comment: Thanks bro i appreciate it